# Como Crio um select menu, que fica na primeira posição com a url corrente

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Como Crio um select menu, que fica na primeira posição com a url corrente, alterando o `selected` das `option`:

```
<select >
  <option value="http://www.test.com/teste1" selected>test1</option>
  <option value="http://www.test.com/teste2">Google</option>
  <option value="http://www.test.com/teste3">YouTube</option>
  <option value="http://www.test.com/teste4">test 4</option>
</select>
```

Exemplo browser url  http://www.test.com/teste4 =

```
`<select >
  <option value="http://www.test.com/teste4" selected>test 4</option>
  <option value="http://www.test.com/teste1/">test1</option>
  <option value="http://www.test.com/teste2">Google</option>
  <option value="http://www.test.com/teste3">YouTube</option>
  </select>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer com jquery assim:

```js
// adicionar a nova option e em seguida seleciona-la
$('select').prepend($('<option>', {
    value: window.location.href,
    text: document.title
})).val(window.location.href);

// Abaixo testes de funcionamento:

  // mostrar o value e text inicial
  console.log($('select').val() + ' | ' + $('select option:selected').text());

  // quando o select for alterado mostrar seu value e text
  $('select').change(function(){
    console.log($(this).val() + ' | ' + $(':selected',this).text()); 
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Titilo da Pagina</title>
<select >
  <option value="http://www.test.test.1/" selected>test1</option>
  <option value="http://www.test.test.2">Google</option>
  <option value="http://www.test.test.3">YouTube</option>
  <option value="http://www.test.test.4">test 4</option>
</select>
```